# How can I temporarily make my staging rails server display errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my dev box when I get a backend error it gives me the error message and a stack trace. However on the staging server it just says

```
"We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."
```

So yeah I know I can check the logs. But what if I want to see the stack trace in the browser. Can I temporarily enable that? This is for Rails 4.04 and Ruby 2.1

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can enable displaying stack trace in your staging environment by settings

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

in your `confing/environments/staging.rb` file of your Rails app.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to see it only part of the time, I simply set consider_all_requests_local depending on an environment variable, so I can switch it on an off as I need it without changing the application's source code:

config/environments/staging.rb:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = !ENV['LOCAL_REQUESTS'].nil?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edariedl`'s answer, but a better one is to handle the exceptions on the server:

[Great tutorial here](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843)

--

**Setup**

```
#config/environments/staging.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
class ExceptionController < ApplicationController

  #Response
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

    #Dependencies
    before_action :status

  #Layout
  layout :layout_status

  ####################
  #      Action      #
  ####################

    #Show
  def show
    respond_with status: @status
  end

  ####################
  #   Dependencies   #
  ####################

  protected

  #Info
  def status
    @exception  = env['action_dispatch.exception']
    @status     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
    @response   = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
  end

  #Format
  def details
    @details ||= {}.tap do |h|
      I18n.with_options scope: [:exception, :show, @response], exception_name: @exception.class.name, exception_message: @exception.message do |i18n|
        h[:name]    = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.title", default: i18n.t(:title, default: @exception.class.name)
        h[:message] = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.description", default: i18n.t(:description, default: @exception.message)
      end
    end
  end
  helper_method :details

  ####################
  #      Layout      #
  ####################

  private

  #Layout
  def layout_status
    @status.to_s == "404" ? "application" : "error"
  end

end
```

**Views**

```
#app/views/exception/show.html.haml
.box
    %h1
        = details[:name]
    %p
        = details[:message]


#app/views/layouts/error.html.haml
!!!
%html
%head

    /Info
    = meta_tags

    /CSS
    :css
        html {
            height: 100%;
            background: #fff;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .error_container {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
            width: 40%;
        }
        .error_container .error {
            display: block; 
            text-align: center;
        }
        .error_container .error img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
        }
        .error_container .message > * {
            display: block;
        }
        .error_container .message strong {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #f00;
        }
        .error_container .contact_info {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 25px 0 0 0;
        }
        .error_container .contact_info a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            opacity: 0.4;
            transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
        }
        .error_container .contact_info a:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

/Body
%body
    .error_container
        = yield
```

---

This, combined with a gem called [ExceptionNotification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) will give you a much more robust exception handling strategy in `staging` and `production`